# Find three vertices of rectangle given one vertex and angle in Java

Tags: java, math

I have a top-left vertex after the rectangle is rotated based on the center and I have the angle(rotated degrees) and width and height. I am trying to find the other three vertices of the rectangle or center of the rectangle.

How to find the other three vertices or center of the rectangle in java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its a math problem. How would you solve it on paper?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi. I am not very good at Maths. if you have a mathematical solution, please let me know, I will try to do that in Java.

Comment: @gopi I’m assuming you also know the rectangles width and height. First find the coordinates of all the vertices when the rectangle is at 0 degrees. Then, rotate the 4 vertices’ coordinates by the angle using a formula which can be found here: https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581058/rotating-rectangle-by-its-center

Comment: yes, @LuckyBandit74  I have the width and height as well. The top-left vertex I have is after rectangle is rotated by some angle based on the center. At this point, I am not sure how to get the coordinates at 0 degrees. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @Abra, the link you suggested didn't help me. The top-left vertex I have is after the rectangle is rotated by some degrees based on the center and I have the width and height as well and need to find the other three vertices or center. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @gopi In that case, it is helpful to know how the rectangle is rotated. That is, if the rectangle is rotated 23 degrees, is that 23 degrees North of East or East of North? To get the rectangle back to the state of 0 degrees in either case, simple rotate it back but negative. That is, if a rectangle is rotated 10 degrees and you have the top left vertex, simply rotate the top left vertex -10 degrees so that the top left vertex is now at 0 degrees

Comment: @LuckyBandit74 rectangle can be rotated in any direction.

Comment: @gopi Ok. I’ll give you an example so you can code the general case: a rectangle is rotated 45 degrees and has a top left vertex at (2, 2). To find the vertex of the rectangle at 0 degrees, rotate 2, 2 by -45 degrees. Then find the other vertices easily. Rotate all vertices 45 degrees to get the vertices of the rotated angle. Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends a bit on your coordinate conventions. The y-axis may be reversed with respect to the image if you are working with graphics in java, but you should check that for yourself. Also, the usual conventions of rotation by an angle, *theta*, is as in the image, but it may be the other way round in your specific situation.

To find the center, *C*, we want to take the x-coordinate *P*x of the known point *P* and add 0.5 * cos(theta) * *w*, where *w* is the width of the rectangle. So

```
Cx = Px + 0.5 * (cos(theta) * w - sin(theta) * h)
```

Likewise,

```
Cy = Py - 0.5 * (sin(theta) * w + cos(theta) * h)
```

If the y-axis is reversed, the minus in front of 0.5 should instead be a plus, and if the rotation is reversed, there should be a minus in front of both theta's.

Since your angle is in degrees, you should remember to convert it to radians to use it with java.Math - something like this:

```
double cx = px + 0.5 * (Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta)) * w + Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta)) * h);
```

You don't actually need the center to find the remaining three corners however:

```
P2x = Px + cos(theta) * w
P2y = Py - sin(theta) * w

P3x = Px + cos(theta) * w - sin(theta) * h
P3y = Py - (sin(theta) * w + cos(theta) * h)

P4x = Px + sin(theta) * h
P4y = Py - cos(theta) * h
```

*P2* is the upper-right corner, *P3* is the opposite corner to *P* and *P4* is the bottom-left corner.

[image: Rotated rectangle]

Comment: thank you. your solution helped me to solve the problem.